# what is different use NVL and Static Value

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have problem with NVL.

When I use this:

```
AND NVL(324,qsn.fk_ifl) = qsn.fk_ifl
```

> the answer is:   324= qsn.fk_ifl.

And my query takes about 20 seconds.

But when I use this:

```
 324 = qsn.fk_ifl
```

My query takes about 6 minutes.

Do you know what is my problem?

When use **NVL** the paln get **Nested Loop** but when use **the other** one the plan get **Hash Join**

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda so why is the first case fast (20 seconds) and the other is slow (6 minutes) ? According to the link you gave, it should be the opposite.

Comment: They should be pretty much equivalent as the `nvl()` is pointless. Look at the execution plans for both queries though and see what is different. Is this repeatable, or did you run them once each but in reverse order (so data caching could have an effect)?

Comment: Sounds weird. But almost certainly not what's actually happening. Please provide a reproducible test case. Otherwise it's unlikely you'll get more than some random - and if you're lucky, well-informed - guesses.

Comment: I think most of the column values of `fk_ifl` are nulls, aren't they?

Comment: I don't know what different between my condition... both of them result me one thing and every time that I run my query time of those are same ( 20's & 6min). when use NVL the paln get Nested Loop but when use the other one the plan get Hash Join